# Open Alias address resolve error

Tags: openalias

I just set up my email address with Open Alias and got the following errors:

**GUI**

```
Address found, but the DNSSEC signatures could not be verified, so this address may be spoofed
```

**CLI**

```
For URL: bob@nowhere.com, WARNING: DNSSEC validation was unsuccessful, this address may not be correct!
```

I didn't get any error with the MyMonero app (not officially released yet though).

Anyway, does anyone have any insight on how to fix this error/warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DNS provider does not support DNSSEC, then your wallet cannot be sure that there is not a man-in-the-middle attack, DNS poisoning or other type of attack giving your wallet an incorrect Monero address.

The only way to resolve this is to move to an alternate DNS nameserver provider that supports DNSSEC.

Comment: Thanks for this. My domain registrar doesn't support DNSSEC, but Cloudflare does. So I set up a free account with Cloudflare and changed to their nameservers. Cloudflare then gave me a 'DS record' that my domain registrar had to add to their system. They did this, now I have DNSSEC and now I get no warning. So I ultimately didn't have to move my domain.